# Merging dynamically generated attributes into a new entry and summing their values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking for some advice on how to properly merge some key/value pairs into a separate database entry and summing their values.
I have a `Task` which has a `Vendor_Upload` which has many `Vendor_Shipping_Logs` which has many `Vendor_Shipping_Log_Products`.  I'm not sure if the deep nesting makes a difference, but the important values to look at here are the `Item_ID` and `Quantity`.

This is currently how the parameters are spit out:

```
Parameters: {
  "task"=>{
    "task_type"=>"Vendor Upload",
    "vendor_upload_attributes"=>{
      "upload_type"=>"Warranty Orders", 
      "vendor_shipping_logs_attributes"=>{
        "1490674883303"=>{
          "guest_name"=>"Martin Crane", 
          "order_number"=>"33101", 
          "vendor_shipping_log_products_attributes"=>{
            "1490675774108"=>{
              "item_id"=>"211", 
              "quantity"=>"3"
            }, 
            "1490675775147"=>{
              "item_id"=>"213", 
              "quantity"=>"6"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "1490674884454"=>{
          "guest_name"=>"Frasier Crane", 
          "order_number"=>"33102", 
          "vendor_shipping_log_products_attributes"=>{
            "1490675808026"=>{
              "item_id"=>"214", 
              "quantity"=>"10"
            }, 
            "1490675808744"=>{
              "item_id"=>"213", 
              "quantity"=>"1"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "1490674885293"=>{
          "guest_name"=>"Niles Crane", 
          "order_number"=>"33103", 
          "vendor_shipping_log_products_attributes"=>{
            "1490675837184"=>{
              "item_id"=>"211", 
              "quantity"=>"3"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "1490674886373"=>{
          "guest_name"=>"Daphne Moon", 
          "order_number"=>"33104", 
          "vendor_shipping_log_products_attributes"=>{
            "1490675852950"=>{
              "item_id"=>"213", 
              "quantity"=>"8"
            }, 
            "1490675853845"=>{
              "item_id"=>"214", 
              "quantity"=>"11"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Upon submission I want to merge each unique `Vendor_Shipping_Log_Product`s `Item_ID`s and sum their quantities into a new `Stockmovement_Batch` as a nested `Stockmovement` to keep my inventories up to date.

See example patameters here of what I would like the output to look like:

```
Parameters: {
  "stockmovement_batch"=>{
    "stockmovement_type"=>"Ecomm Order", 
    "stockmovements_attributes"=>{
      "1490676054881"=>{
        "item_id"=>"211", 
        "adjust_quantity"=>"-6"
      }, 
      "1490676055897"=>{
        "item_id"=>"213", 
        "adjust_quantity"=>"-15"
      }, 
      "1490676057616"=>{
        "item_id"=>"214", 
        "adjust_quantity"=>"-21"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this something I can do all in one simple go, or do I have to stick with doing each process in a separate form?

Comment: I don't get how the "1490676054881" keys in the result should be derived if the result is from summarizing the order.

Comment: The result should be summarizing unique Item ID's.  So if there's two separate orders for Item 213, one for a quantity of 3, and another for a quantity of two, the Stockmovement Key should be 213 at a quantity of -5.  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to separate out the values you want to iterate through:

```
data = params.require("task")
                      .require("vendor_upload_attributes")
                      .require("vendor_shipping_logs_attributes")
```

Then pull the `vendor_shipping_log_products_attributes` and flatten it to an array of hashes:

```
logs = data.values.map do |h|
  h["vendor_shipping_log_products_attributes"].values
end.flatten


# => [{"item_id"=>"211", "quantity"=>"3"}, {"item_id"=>"213", "quantity"=>"6"}, {"item_id"=>"214", "quantity"=>"10"}, {"item_id"=>"213", "quantity"=>"1"}, {"item_id"=>"211", "quantity"=>"3"}, {"item_id"=>"213", "quantity"=>"8"}, {"item_id"=>"214", "quantity"=>"11"}]
```

Then we merge the data by creating a intermediary hash where we use the  item_id as keys.

```
stockmovements = logs.each_with_object({}) do |hash, memo|
  id = hash["item_id"]
  memo[id] ||= []
  memo[id].push(hash["quantity"].to_i)
end

# => {"211"=>[3, 3], "213"=>[6, 1, 8], "214"=>[10, 11]}
```

We then can then map the result and sum the values:

```
stockmovements.map do |(k,v)|
  {
     item_id: k,
     adjust_quantity: 0 - v.sum
  }
end

# => [{:item_id=>"211", :adjust_quantity=>-6}, {:item_id=>"213", :adjust_quantity=>-15}, {:item_id=>"214", :adjust_quantity=>-21}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I'll have time later this evening to take a deep dive into the code you supplied and see how it works.  I'm still new, so it might take me a bit to wrap my head around it.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Most of this just using the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html) module which lets you iterate through arrays and hashes in a functional way in ruby instead of using a bunch of loops and mutating variables as you would in a procedural language.